# How do I add a product variance title to the order information page?

Tags: commerce

I am looking to have the Product Title appear in the Order Information page. However, the data is pulling the price versus the product title. I attempted to change the views. No luck. I am not a developer, so, if development is needed, okay. Just looking for an easy way to make this work.

[image: Shopping Cart]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've set up a subscription product variance named 1-Year Subscription. The product is appearing in the shopping cart correctly. I was able to make this work via the Checkout Block View. When proceeding to checkout, the product description appears as the price. I attempted to edit the Checkout Order Summary View with no change. After a little research, it appears that the Checkout Order Summary View is no longer tied to the checkout page?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please edit the question to include any detail that is useful to answer it. The purpose of comments isn't giving that information.

Comment: Added two more screenshots. 1st is the shopping cart, second is the view for the Checkout Order Summary View, the third is Order Summary page.

Answer (score 0):

That second column, 'Price: $34' is created from the Summary display of the Product variant. If you've created your own new Product variant type, it won't have any Summary display, so Commerce uses the Default display, which shows the Price.

To fix it, go to Commerce > Configuration > Products > Product variation types, then choose ‘Manage display’ for your Product variation type. Click Custom Display Settings, put a tick next to ‘Summary’, and Save.

Now you’ll a see choice of Default or Summary display. Click on Summary, then rearrange the fields to show what you want to appear in that second column.

On our site I changed it to show only the product's name, so:

- FIELD: Product
- LABEL: Hidden
- FORMAT: Label, with ‘Link label to the referenced entity’ disabled

Save, clear caches, and check the order information page shows what you want.